# kapacitor not running indicate fail

Tags: go, influxdb, telegraf, kapacitor

help my apacitor is not runnning, actually im running influxdb in the same server that kapacitor and telegraf, but my kapacitor don't work

```
kapacitor.service - Time series data processing engine.
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/kapacitor.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Thu 2019-01-03 17:56:38 UTC; 3s ago
     Docs: https://github.com/influxdb/kapacitor
  Process: 2502 ExecStart=/usr/bin/kapacitord -config /etc/kapacitor/kapacitor.conf $KAPACITOR_OPTS (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
 Main PID: 2502 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Jan 03 17:56:38 ip-172-31-43-67 systemd[1]: kapacitor.service: Service hold-off time over, scheduling restart.
Jan 03 17:56:38 ip-172-31-43-67 systemd[1]: kapacitor.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 5.
Jan 03 17:56:38 ip-172-31-43-67 systemd[1]: Stopped Time series data processing engine..
Jan 03 17:56:38 ip-172-31-43-67 systemd[1]: kapacitor.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
Jan 03 17:56:38 ip-172-31-43-67 systemd[1]: kapacitor.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Jan 03 17:56:38 ip-172-31-43-67 systemd[1]: Failed to start Time series data processing engine..
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i did find the solution for myself:

```
[[influxdb]]
enabled = true
name = "localhost"
default = true
urls = ["http://localhost:8086"]
username = "user"
password = "password"
```

you must take in count that you will need has an user create in influxdb before